# MQTT terminate infinite loop while subscribing to a topic in python

Tags: python, mqtt

I am connecting with a device using AWS like the following:

```
# Define the callback function to collect received messages
def on_message_received(topic, payload, **kwargs):
    payload_str = payload.decode('utf-8')
    # Parse the string as a JSON dictionary
    payload_dict = json.loads(payload_str)
    print("payload", payload_dict)
    messages.append(payload_dict)


# Initialize the MQTT connection variables
event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)
mqtt_connection = None  # MQTT connection object
messages = []  # List to store received messages


def connect_mqtt():
    global mqtt_connection
    try:
        # Connect to AWS IoT Core
        print("Connecting to {} with client ID '{}'...".format(ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID))
        mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
            endpoint=ENDPOINT,
            cert_filepath=PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE,
            pri_key_filepath=PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY,
            client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
            ca_filepath=PATH_TO_AMAZON_ROOT_CA_1,
            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
            clean_session=False,
            keep_alive_secs=60
        )
        connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()
        connect_future.result()
        print("Connected!")
    except awscrt.exceptions.AwsCrtError as e:
        print("AWS CRT Error:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)


def disconnect_mqtt():
    global mqtt_connection
    try:
        if mqtt_connection:
            # Disconnect from AWS IoT Core
            mqtt_connection.disconnect()
            print("Connection Disconnected")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while disconnecting:", e)


def run_command(command_id, start_stop):
    global messages

    test_dict = {
        "command_id": command_id,  # Initialize command_id within the function
        "payload": {}
    }

    if start_stop == "start":
        connect_mqtt()  # Connect to MQTT if starting

        # Publish test data to the "commands" topic
        print('Begin Publish')
        test_dict["command"] = "start"
        data = json.dumps(test_dict)
        message = {"message": data}
        # mqtt_connection.publish(topic=COMMANDS_TOPIC, payload=data, qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        print("Published: '{}' to the topic: '{}'".format(json.dumps(message), COMMANDS_TOPIC))

        # Subscribe to the "events" topic in a loop
        while True:
            try:
                # Continuously check for incoming messages
                mqtt_connection.subscribe(topic=EVENTS_TOPIC, qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, callback=on_message_received)
                print("mqtt_connection", mqtt_connection)
                print("mqtt connection messages", messages)
         
                time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for a while to allow message processing
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break  # Exit the loop gracefully if a keyboard interrupt is received

    elif start_stop == "stop":
        connect_mqtt()  # Connect to MQTT if starting

        # Publish a "stop" command
        test_dict["command"] = "stop"
        data = json.dumps(test_dict)
        mqtt_connection.publish(topic=COMMANDS_TOPIC, payload=data, qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        disconnect_mqtt()

    return messages


class StartMQTT(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        command_id = request.GET['command_id']
        messages = run_command(command_id, "start")
        return Response({"message": "MQTT connection started successfully", "messages": messages},
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class StopMQTT(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        command_id = request.GET['command_id']
        run_command(command_id, "stop")
        return Response({"message": "MQTT connection stopped successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class MQTTReplies(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(messages)
```

Now if i run the function `run_command` it publishes a message and then gets in the loop where it keeps on getting the messages via mqtt_connection.subscribe and I can access those messages with `MQTTReplies` API. Now when I run the `StopMQTT` API it closes the connection by publishing another message but the loop from `StartMQTT` is still on, however it does not effect as there is no more messages coming from the device.

But when I re run the start command the new messages are added into the previous one because that loop hasn't terminated so every time i start it i have the whole history of messages.

how do i terminate the connection when there are no more messages coming from the `mqtt_connection.subscribe(topic=EVENTS_TOPIC, qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, callback=on_message_received)` command?

Comment: Why are you calling `mqtt_connection.subscribe` in a loop? You should only need to call this once to establish the subscription (the broker will then send you the relevant messages and they will be delivered to you via `on_message_received`). See [this example](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/pubsub.py#L115).